# Issues with Meteor JS on Macbook Air M1 2020

Tags: macos, github, npm, curl, meteor

I am Currently running meteor JS on my Macbook Air M1 2020 on Ventura 13.3.1. While I was trying to learn how to work with meteor, I came across this particular issue that causes a lot of problems.

I downloaded Meteor JS using :

`curl https://install.meteor.com/ | sh`

Cloned a repo that already has an application written:

`git clone https://github.com/jd4rider/chatsandblogs.git`

I ran:

`meteor npm install`

I Encountered my many problems.I got 16 vulnerabilities (5 moderate, 8 high, 3 critical).

I Ignored that and ran :

`meteor`

This worked for a while and then showed a bunch of errors at the step of Downloading zephraph@namespace@1.0.0.:

```
(base) aniruddhasharma@Dhirendras-MacBook-Air chatsandblogs % meteor
[[[[[ ~/Desktop/Blog_Application/chatsandblogs ]]]]]

=> Started proxy.                             
=> Meteor 2.12 is available. Update this project with 'meteor update'.
=> Started MongoDB.                           
=> Errors prevented startup:                  
   
   While downloading accounts-base@1.4.4...:
   error: certificate has expired
   
   While downloading accounts-facebook@1.3.2...:
   error: certificate has expired
   
   While downloading accounts-oauth@1.1.16...:
   error: certificate has expired
   
   While downloading accounts-password@1.5.1...:
   error: certificate has expired
   
   While downloading aldeed:collection2@2.0.1...:
   error: certificate has expired
   
   While downloading aldeed:simple-schema@1.0.3...:
   error: certificate has expired
   
   While downloading allow-deny@1.1.0...:
   error: certificate has expired
   
   While downloading autoupdate@1.6.0...:
   error: certificate has expired
   
   While downloading babel-compiler@7.3.4...:
   error: certificate has expired
   
   While downloading babel-runtime@1.3.0...:
   error: certificate has expired
   
   While downloading base64@1.0.11...:
   error: certificate has expired
   
   While downloading blaze@2.3.3...:
   error: certificate has expired
   
   While downloading blaze-html-templates@1.1.2...:
   error: certificate has expired
   
   While downloading blaze-tools@1.0.10...:
   error: certificate has expired
   
   While downloading boilerplate-generator@1.6.0...:
   error: certificate has expired
   
   While downloading caching-compiler@1.2.1...:
   error: certificate has expired
   
   While downloading caching-html-compiler@1.1.3...:
   error: certificate has expired
   
   While downloading callback-hook@1.1.0...:
   error: certificate has expired
   
   While downloading check@1.3.1...:
   error: certificate has expired
   
   While downloading dburles:collection-helpers@1.0.4...:
   error: certificate has expired
   
   While downloading ddp@1.4.0...:
   error: certificate has expired
   
   While downloading ddp-client@2.3.3...:
   error: certificate has expired
   
   While downloading ddp-rate-limiter@1.0.7...:
   error: certificate has expired
   
   While downloading ddp-server@2.3.0...:
   error: certificate has expired
   
   While downloading deps@1.0.12...:
   error: certificate has expired
   
   While downloading diff-sequence@1.1.1...:
   error: certificate has expired
   
   While downloading dynamic-import@0.5.1...:
   error: certificate has expired
   
   While downloading ecmascript@0.12.7...:
   error: certificate has expired
   
   While downloading ecmascript-runtime@0.7.0...:
   error: certificate has expired
   
   While downloading ecmascript-runtime-client@0.8.0...:
   error: certificate has expired
   
   While downloading ecmascript-runtime-server@0.7.1...:
   error: certificate has expired
   
   While downloading ejson@1.1.0...:
   error: certificate has expired
   
   While downloading email@1.2.3...:
   error: certificate has expired
   
   While downloading facebook-oauth@1.6.0...:
   error: certificate has expired
   
   While downloading fetch@0.1.1...:
   error: certificate has expired
   
   While downloading fortawesome:fontawesome@4.2.0_2...:
   error: certificate has expired
   
   While downloading geojson-utils@1.0.10...:
   error: certificate has expired
   
   While downloading html-tools@1.0.11...:
   error: certificate has expired
   
   While downloading htmljs@1.0.11...:
   error: certificate has expired
   
   While downloading http@1.4.2...:
   error: certificate has expired
   
   While downloading id-map@1.1.0...:
   error: certificate has expired
   
   While downloading inter-process-messaging@0.1.0...:
   error: certificate has expired
   
   While downloading jquery@1.11.11...:
   error: certificate has expired
   
   While downloading kadira:blaze-layout@2.0.1...:
   error: certificate has expired
   
   While downloading kadira:flow-router@2.12.1...:
   error: certificate has expired
   
   While downloading launch-screen@1.1.1...:
   error: certificate has expired
   
   While downloading lepozepo:accounting@1.0.0...:
   error: certificate has expired
   
   While downloading livedata@1.0.18...:
   error: certificate has expired
   
   While downloading logging@1.1.20...:
   error: certificate has expired
   
   While downloading matteodem:server-session@0.4.2...:
   error: certificate has expired
   
   While downloading meteor@1.9.3...:
   error: certificate has expired
   
   While downloading meteor-base@1.4.0...:
   error: certificate has expired
   
   While downloading meteoris:core@0.2.3...:
   error: certificate has expired
   
   While downloading meteoris:flash@0.0.3...:
   error: certificate has expired
   
   While downloading meteoris:form-validation@0.0.2...:
   error: certificate has expired
   
   While downloading meteoris:formatter@0.0.7...:
   error: certificate has expired
   
   While downloading meteoris:grid-view@0.0.2...:
   error: certificate has expired
   
   While downloading meteoris:role@0.1.3...:
   error: certificate has expired
   
   While downloading meteoris:theme-admin@0.0.6...:
   error: certificate has expired
   
   While downloading meteoris:user@0.1.1...:
   error: certificate has expired
   
   While downloading mfactory:admin-lte@0.0.2...:
   error: certificate has expired
   
   While downloading minifier-css@1.4.2...:
   error: certificate has expired
   
   While downloading minifier-js@2.4.1...:
   error: certificate has expired
   
   While downloading minimongo@1.4.5...:
   error: certificate has expired
   
   While downloading mnmtanish:call@1.1.1...:
   error: certificate has expired
   
   While downloading mobile-experience@1.0.5...:
   error: certificate has expired
   
   While downloading mobile-status-bar@1.0.14...:
   error: certificate has expired
   
   While downloading modern-browsers@0.1.4...:
   error: certificate has expired
   
   While downloading modules@0.13.0...:
   error: certificate has expired
   
   While downloading modules-runtime@0.10.3...:
   error: certificate has expired
   
   While downloading momentjs:moment@2.8.4...:
   error: certificate has expired
   
   While downloading mongo@1.6.2...:
   error: certificate has expired
   
   While downloading mongo-decimal@0.1.1...:
   error: certificate has expired
   
   While downloading mongo-id@1.0.7...:
   error: certificate has expired
   
   While downloading npm-bcrypt@0.9.3...:
   error: certificate has expired
   
   While downloading npm-mongo@3.1.2...:
   error: certificate has expired
   
   While downloading oauth@1.2.8...:
   error: certificate has expired
   
   While downloading oauth2@1.2.1...:
   error: certificate has expired
   
   While downloading observe-sequence@1.0.16...:
   error: certificate has expired
   
   While downloading promise@0.11.2...:
   error: certificate has expired
   
   While downloading random@1.1.0...:
   error: certificate has expired
   
   While downloading rate-limit@1.0.9...:
   error: certificate has expired
   
   While downloading reactive-dict@1.3.0...:
   error: certificate has expired
   
   While downloading reactive-var@1.0.11...:
   error: certificate has expired
   
   While downloading reload@1.3.0...:
   error: certificate has expired
   
   While downloading reywood:publish-composite@1.3.6...:
   error: certificate has expired
   
   While downloading rochal:slimscroll@1.3.3...:
   error: certificate has expired
   
   While downloading routepolicy@1.1.0...:
   error: certificate has expired
   
   While downloading sacha:spin@2.0.4...:
   error: certificate has expired
   
   While downloading service-configuration@1.0.11...:
   error: certificate has expired
   
   While downloading shell-server@0.4.0...:
   error: certificate has expired
   
   While downloading simple:reactive-method@1.0.2...:
   error: certificate has expired
   
   While downloading socket-stream-client@0.2.2...:
   error: certificate has expired
   
   While downloading spacebars@1.0.15...:
   error: certificate has expired
   
   While downloading spacebars-compiler@1.1.3...:
   error: certificate has expired
   
   While downloading srp@1.0.12...:
   error: certificate has expired
   
   While downloading standard-minifier-css@1.5.3...:
   error: certificate has expired
   
   While downloading standard-minifier-js@2.4.1...:
   error: certificate has expired
   
   While downloading templating@1.3.2...:
   error: certificate has expired
   
   While downloading templating-compiler@1.3.3...:
   error: certificate has expired
   
   While downloading templating-runtime@1.3.2...:
   error: certificate has expired
   
   While downloading templating-tools@1.1.2...:
   error: certificate has expired
   
   While downloading tracker@1.2.0...:
   error: certificate has expired
   
   While downloading twbs:bootstrap@3.3.6...:
   error: certificate has expired
   
   While downloading ui@1.0.13...:
   error: certificate has expired
   
   While downloading underscore@1.0.10...:
   error: certificate has expired
   
   While downloading url@1.2.0...:
   error: certificate has expired
   
   While downloading webapp@1.7.4...:
   error: certificate has expired
   
   While downloading webapp-hashing@1.0.9...:
   error: certificate has expired
   
   While downloading zephraph:namespace@1.0.0...:
   error: certificate has expired
   
=> Your application has errors. Waiting for file change.
   Downloading zephraph:namespace@1.0.0...   /
```

I tried to look into the issue of what version of meteor I was running and came across this anomaly:

```
(base) aniruddhasharma@Dhirendras-MacBook-Air chatsandblogs % meteor --version
Meteor 1.8.1                                  
(base) aniruddhasharma@Dhirendras-MacBook-Air chatsandblogs % cd ..
(base) aniruddhasharma@Dhirendras-MacBook-Air Blog_Application % meteor --version
Meteor 2.12
```

Why is the application having an old version of meteor while I have 2.12 installed. Also when i tired to update the verion of meteor inside the application, I received these errors:

```
(base) aniruddhasharma@Dhirendras-MacBook-Air chatsandblogs % meteor update --release 2.12
=> Errors while initializing project:         
                                              
While selecting package versions:
error: Conflict: Constraint accounts-base@1.2.1 is not satisfied by accounts-base 2.2.8.
Constraints on package "accounts-base":
* accounts-base@~2.2.8 <- top level
* accounts-base@1.2.1 <- meteoris:role 0.1.3
* accounts-base@2.2.7 <- accounts-password 2.3.4 <- meteoris:role 0.1.3
* accounts-base@1.2.1 <- meteoris:user 0.1.1
* accounts-base@2.2.5 <- service-configuration 1.3.1 <- accounts-oauth 1.4.2 <- accounts-facebook 1.3.3 <- meteoris:user
0.1.1
* accounts-base@2.2.5 <- service-configuration 1.3.1 <- meteoris:user 0.1.1
* accounts-base@2.0.0 <- accounts-facebook 1.3.3 <- meteoris:user 0.1.1
* accounts-base@2.2.6 <- accounts-oauth 1.4.2 <- accounts-facebook 1.3.3 <- meteoris:user 0.1.1

Conflict: Constraint accounts-password@1.1.3 is not satisfied by accounts-password 2.3.4.
Constraints on package "accounts-password":
* accounts-password@~2.3.4 <- top level
* accounts-password@1.1.3 <- meteoris:role 0.1.3
* accounts-password@1.1.3 <- meteoris:user 0.1.1
```